# PHP login script only works once

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

I have created a modal login script that only works once. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. Sometimes it will send the `$_POST` data and sometimes it won't. I cannot figure out what is going on.

Here is how I call the login script manually:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('LoginModal').style.display='block'">Login</button>
```

Here is the actual form:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
        <img src="/Images/FrontierLogo294-117.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><b>UserName</b></label>
        <input class="Login" type="text" placeholder="UserName required (use CorpID)" name="UserName" required><br>
        <label><b>Password</b></label>
        <input class="Login" type="password" placeholder="Password not currently required" name="password">
        <button type="submit" class="Green">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('LoginModal').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <!--span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span-->
    </div>
<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    //error_log(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa")." LoginModal.php line 16 HTTP_REFERER: " .$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. "\n",3,'D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\Helper\LogPHP.txt'); ?>
</form>
<script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('LoginModal');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is where I'm trying to set the CorpID in a `Cookie`:

```
if(isset($_POST['UserName']))
{
    $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];    
    if(isset($UserName))
    {
        $Expiration = time() + (60*60*24*7);
        if(isset($_COOKIE['UserName']))
        {
            setcookie("UserName",$_COOKIE['UserName'],$Expiration,'/','.engsys.corp.ftr.com',0);
            setcookie("CookieTime",$Expiration,time() + (60*60*24*7),'/','.engsys.corp.ftr.com',0);
            error_log(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa")." AdminPage.php line 40 Cookie: " .$_COOKIE['UserName']. "\n",3,'D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\Helper\LogPHP.txt');
            echo "<script>location.href = 'http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. "'</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie("UserName",$UserName,$Expiration,'/');
            setcookie("CookieTime",$Expiration,time() + (60*60*24*7),'/','.engsys.corp.ftr.com',0);
            error_log(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa")." AdminPage.php line 47 Cookie: " .$_COOKIE['UserName']. "\n",3,'D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\Helper\LogPHP.txt');
            echo "<script>location.href = 'http://" .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. "'</script>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    error_log(date("Y/m/d h:i:sa")." AdminPage.php line 61 UserName was not set!\n",3,'D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\Helper\LogPHP.txt');
}
```

I have tried this without the `echo` to reload the page and I still get the same results, the `$_COOKIE` does not get updated. When I first login it works fine, then whenever I try to update it and login as someone else it does not work. I'm pretty sure my code is sound it just isn't doing what I think it should be.

This is all in the same file except the code for the modal is in a separate file that is `include`d. The files are called `AdminPage.php` and `LoginModal.php` respectively.

Where am I messing up?

Comment: What part is line 61?

Comment: I think your problem is that you send your POST to the referer.

Comment: @Oluwaseye what do you mean about line 61? In the error_log? that is just putting that note in the error log if it gets to it.

Comment: My bad  i thought you copied it off the browser

Comment: @masterfloda the referrer is the page that it is coming from right? In this case, it is the `AdminPage.php`. Where should I be sending it if not there? That is where to cookies are set.

Comment: @Oluwaseye No, I have a lot of `error_log` being used so I started putting the file name and line number in it so I can find exactly where the log lines are coming from.

Comment: It would help to have your code somewhere like codepen to see exactly what the issue is

Comment: @Oluwaseye I attempted to add it to codepen (I just signed up), but it doesn't show `PHP` correctly and so isn't working. I can add a link (I think) to my question above if you want.

Comment: I suspect the 'action="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>"' is causing problems. Can you try to replace it with the actual url to the php file?

Comment: @Mike you can't be sure that the referrer is always AdminPage. If you go to LoginModal.php directly it does not have a referrer. Even worse: If you come from another website, this is the referrer (and you would POST your credentials there). You should hardcode AdminPage.php as the form action. But apart from that, I think i found your problem. You post to adminPage, it sets the cookie and then you print a JS that actually reloads the page with GET (which will go to line 61)

Comment: @ManuelOtto It won't always be the `AdminPage.php` that this comes from. A new user (or when the cookie expires) will get the Login form from where ever they are. I can manually invoke the login page from the AdminPage.

Comment: @masterfloda I have tried with the `action` hard coded. It made no difference. I have tried without the reloading of the page as well. I added it to see if that would help. It did not, it still doesn't update the cookie for the username.

Comment: @Mike oooooh, it took me a while to find the error. You don't override the cookie value but use the existing one! I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you log in as `userA` for the very first time you will hit line 47 and the cookie `UserName` will be set with the value `userA`. If you then log in as `userB` it will hit line 40. But as a cookie value you do not use the new username but the one already stored in the cookie! Use `$_POST['UserName']` instead of `$_COOKIE['UserName']`

```
setcookie("UserName",$_POST['UserName'],$Expiration,'/','.engsys.corp.ftr.com',0);
```

Comment: Well that got me further! Now though I'm getting the error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\dev\FrontierReports\Menu.php:42) in D:\WebContent\engsys.corp.ftr.com\dev\FrontierReports\AdminPage.php on line 38`

Comment: did you echo something before calling setcookie? You'd have to make all calls to setcookie before outputting anything...

Comment: There's the menu that gets set before the cookie. Would that be it? I don't see any other echos.

Comment: I got it! I did the change that you suggested then I moved the echo that reloads the page to be before the `setcookie` instead of commented out. Now it is working. I will still need to test a fresh login, but so far so good!